# Understanding RDD and DataSet

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

From the DataSet and RDD documentation,

DataSet:

> A Dataset is a strongly typed collection of domain-specific objects
>   that can be transformed in parallel using functional or relational
>   operations. Each dataset also has an untyped view called a DataFrame,
>   which is a Dataset of Row

RDD:

> RDD represents an immutable,partitioned collection of elements that
>   can be operated on in parallel

Also, it is said the difference between them:

> The major difference is, dataset is collection of domain specific
>   objects where as RDD is collection of any object. Domain object part
>   of definition signifies the schema part of dataset. So dataset API is
>   always strongly typed and optimized using schema where RDD is not.

I have two questions here;

1. what does it mean `dataset is collection of domain specific objects while RDD is collection of any object`,Given a case class `Person`, I thought DataSet[Person] and RDD[Person] are both collection of domain specific objects
2. `dataset API is always strongly typed and optimized using schema where RDD is not` Why is it said that dataset API always strongly typed while RDD not? I thought RDD[Person] is also strong typed

Comment: Who marks my question to be closed? Why should be it closed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strongly  typed `Dataset` (not `DataFrame`) is a collection of record types (Scala `Products`) which are mapped to internal storage format using so called `Encoders`,  while `RDD` can store arbitrary serializable (`Serializable` or Kryo serializable object). Therefore as a container `RDD` is much more generic than `Dataset`.

Following:

> . So dataset API is always strongly typed (...) where RDD is not.

is an utter absurd, showing that you shouldn't trust everything you can find on the Internet. In general `Dataset` API has significantly weaker type protections, than `RDD`. This is particularly obvious when working `Dataset[Row]`, but applies to any `Dataset`.

Consider for example following:

```
case class FooBar(id: Int, foos: Seq[Int])

 Seq[(Integer, Integer)]((1, null))
   .toDF.select($"_1" as "id", array($"_2") as "foos")
   .as[FooBar]
```

which clearly breaks type safety.